# How to add Id to widgets on screen in GWT for testing purpose

Tags: user-interface, testing, gwt

I need to add object id to widgets on my screen so I am able to test the widgets correctly at the test time. I tried using **DOM.SetElementProperty(element,id,value)** but this is deprecated. Is there any other way I can assign the id to Widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
myWidget.getElement().setId("123");
```

For rows in a CellTable or DataGrid:

```
myCellTable.getRowElement(rowIndex).setId("123");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add an id for test purposes only you should use the static method of `UIObject` `ensureDebugId(Element elem, String id)`. Then make a gwt.xml for testing only (inherit your gwt.xml) and and `<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.Debug" />`. Without the Debug, the id is not generated in the code. So you'll these id's are specific for testing.

Comment: I am looking here particularly for adding id to rows in the Celltable. Can you please let me know how this can be done.